# cx_freeze fails to create exe with pandas library

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pandas, cx-freeze

Having problems creating exe using cx_freeze with a Pandas library. I have seen lots of others having issues with numPy but I was able to successfully bring in numPy. My big pain point has been Pandas. Is there anything in Pandas that might be causing to fail?

**Setup file**

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
build_exe_options = {
"includes": ['numpy', 'pandas'],
"packages": [],
'excludes' : [],
"include_files": []}

setup(
    name = "appName",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "",
    author = "Dengar",
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables = [Executable("appName.py")]
    )
```

**Code snippet** *showing what I am pulling in*

```
import pyodbc
import numpy as np
import pandas.io.sql as psql
from pandas import  DataFrame, Series, date_range
import datetime

print("Hello World")
```

**Here is the Error log I get**

> ```
> > Stamped: build\exe.win-amd64-2.7\appName.exe Traceback (most recent
> > call last):   File "setup.py", line 17, in <module>
> >     executables = [Executable("pyodbc.py")]   File "C:\Users\Dengar\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py",
> > line 365, in setup
> >     distutils.core.setup(**attrs)   File "C:\Users\Dengar\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\distutils\core.py",
> > line 152, in setup
> >     dist.run_commands()   File "C:\Users\Dengar\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\distutils\dist.py",
> > line 953, in run_commands
> >     self.run_command(cmd)   File "C:\Users\Dengar\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\distutils\dist.py",
> > line 972, in run_command
> >     cmd_obj.run()   File "C:\Users\Dengar\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\distutils\command\build.py",
> > line 127, in run
> >     self.run_command(cmd_name)   File "C:\Users\Dengar\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\distutils\cmd.py",
> > line 326, in run_command
> >     self.distribution.run_command(command)   File "C:\Users\Dengar\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\distutils\dist.py",
> > line 972, in run_command
> >     cmd_obj.run()   File "C:\Users\Dengar\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py",
> > line 235, in run
> >     freezer.Freeze()   File "C:\Users\Dengar\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py",
> > line 582, in Freeze
> >     self.compress, self.copyDependentFiles)   File "C:\Users\Dengar\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py",
> > line 492, in _WriteModules
> >     module.Create(finder)   File "C:\Users\Dengar\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py",
> > line 714, in Create
> >     module.file, module.name) cx_Freeze.freezer.ConfigError: no file named sys (for module boto.compat.sys)
> ```

If I remove Pandas from my Setup file and snippet and leave Numpy I have a functional executable. Anybody run into this issue? The exe gets created but none of the supporting files is added to the build directory. On open of the exe, I the program immediately crashes.

I am running python27 64 bit on anaconda windows 8 machine.

Comment: It's falling down on something in boto, which I guess must be pulled in by some optional code in pandas. If you don't need boto, try adding it to excludes.

Comment: @ThomasK I should have posted an updated to this. It appears that gbq.py, Google Big Query api, was the issue within pandas. I commented it out and was able to convert to exe without a problem.

Comment: I also want to note that I ended up using py2exe. I was unable to get cx_Freeze to work.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following to your build_exe_options:

```
'build_exe': {
    'excludes': ['boto.compat.sys',
                 'boto.compat._sre',
                 'boto.compat._json',
                 'boto.compat._locale',
                 'boto.compat._struct',
                 'boto.compat.array'],
}
```

I looked at boto/compat.py and did not see a sys module being imported. By excluding the above list of modules, boto/compat.py is still included.

After excluding 'boto.compat.sys' and 'boto.compat._sre', I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 31, in <module>
    executables=executables
  File "/Users/king/virtual_envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cx_Freeze/dist.py", line 362, in setup
    distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 127, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Users/king/virtual_envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cx_Freeze/dist.py", line 232, in run
    freezer.Freeze()
  File "/Users/king/virtual_envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cx_Freeze/freezer.py", line 610, in Freeze
    self.compress, self.copyDependentFiles)
  File "/Users/king/virtual_envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cx_Freeze/freezer.py", line 586, in _WriteModules
    path = os.pathsep.join([origPath] + module.parent.path)
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "NoneType") to list
```

I ran `ipython` and then typed:

```
In [1]: pdb
Automatic pdb calling has been turned ON

In [2]: run setup.py build
```

To get access to `module` from `module.parent.path`:

```
ipdb> module
<Module name='boto.compat._json', file='/Users/king/virtual_envs/py27/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_json.so'>
```

NOTE: _json.so is the built in json module. This means putting it in the includes specifically should include it. I did not since other packages caused cx_freeze to pick it up automatically. Excluding 'boto.compat._json' did the trick.

I repeated this until I the whole thing built. I confirmed all base modules were picked up by cx_freeze (_sre, _json, _locale, _struct, array) so I did not need to add them manually to includes.

So, your updated script will look like:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
build_exe_options = {
"includes": ['numpy', 'pandas'],
"packages": [],
'excludes' : ['boto.compat.sys',
              'boto.compat._sre',
              'boto.compat._json',
              'boto.compat._locale',
              'boto.compat._struct',
              'boto.compat.array'],
"include_files": []}

setup(
    name = "appName",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "",
    author = "Dengar",
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables = [Executable("appName.py")]
)
```

Comment: Thanks Brandon for following up. Like I mentioned in a comment above, I ended up using py2exe and excluding GBQ, Google Big Query, from pandas library. Your solution might work as well.

Answer (score 1):

The following should help you get over this problem (and may lead you to the next one of missing dependencies ;) )

Checking the code for freeze.py, there is a case that is not checked, so I made the following changes to freezer.py:

line 600, from

```
    try:
        if module.parent is not None:
            path = os.pathsep.join([origPath] + module.parent.path)
            os.environ["PATH"] = path
        self._CopyFile(module.file, target, copyDependentFiles)
    finally:
        os.environ["PATH"] = origPath
```

to:

```
    try:
        if module.parent is not None:
            if module.parent.path is not None:
                path = os.pathsep.join([origPath] + module.parent.path)
                os.environ["PATH"] = path
                self._CopyFile(module.file, target, copyDependentFiles)
            else:
                path = os.pathsep.join([origPath, os.path.dirname(module.parent.file)])
                os.environ["PATH"] = path
                print '========================================================'
    finally:
        os.environ["PATH"] = origPath
```