# Error using cx_freeze and PyInstaller to make an .exe file in Python (which includes xlwings)

Tags: python, excel, pyinstaller, cx-freeze, xlwings

[Yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37889467/how-to-make-python-change-xlsx-files-when-excel-app-is-opened) I asked a question about using Excel and Python simultaneously. The solution was found: using `xlwings` package.

However, there is another problem connected with that - I can not save my `.py` file as an executable file (`exe`).

Here is the code I try to save:

doiterations.py

```
    import xlwings as xl
    import numpy
    import time

    wb = xl.Workbook.active()
    sheet = wb.active

    iter = input("How many iterations do you need? \n")
    i = 0
    cell1 = raw_input("Write a column where you need to iterate \n")
    cell2 = int(raw_input("Write a row where you need to iterate \n"))

    while True:
        i += 1
            if i <= iter:
                arg = numpy.random.uniform()
                xl.Range("%s%d" % (cell1, cell2)).value = arg
            else:
                break

        wb.save()
        print("Done!")

        time.sleep(2)
```

I tried to use `cx_freezer` and made a `setup.py` file with the following code:

```
        from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

        setup(
            name = "Uniform distribution generator",
            version = "1.0",
            description = "Uniform distribution generator",
            executables = [Executable("doiterations.py")]
        )
```

Such `setyp.py` files with the similar code properly worked with other modules. However, this time I got an error `no file named sys`:

```
    cx_Freeze.freezer.ConfigError: no file named sys (for module collections.sys)
```

[image]

I tried to use `PyInstaller` package with the following command:

[image]

and again faced an error:

```
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
```

[image]

I searched through Google and Stackoverflow and found some comments on this problem that may help to find the solution:

https://mborgerson.com/creating-an-executable-from-a-python-script
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/192592-making-an-exe-file-with-pyinstaller/

[cx_freeze fails to create exe with pandas library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23094751/cx-freeze-fails-to-create-exe-with-pandas-library/27514272#27514272)
[cx-freeze error on build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24418841/cx-freeze-error-on-build)
[Traceback from CX_Freeze doesn't make sense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28685401/traceback-from-cx-freeze-doesnt-make-sense)

My version of Python is 2.7.

Please, help to solve the problem and create a working executable file!

Comment: Please post text as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), not images.

Comment: @zondo If you tell me how to copy text from a control panel of Windows (cmd), I will do it with a great pleasure.

Comment: @shivsn Could you clarify me, please, where should I exactly put your code in? A full algorithm would also be helpful.

Comment: @shivsn It does not work either with `setup.py` or with `doiterations.py`. How did you use it?

Comment: You could try moving your files to another location, like `c:\temp\test` i.e. a path that does include other characters than ascii.

Comment: @shivsn Did not work either. Returns the same error.

Comment: @Alex what about pyinstaller?

Comment: @J.J.Hakala Unfortunately, it did not work with `cx_freezer`. He returns the same error as I mentioned before (`ConfigError`). It also did not work with `PyInstaller` (returns the same `UnicodeDecodeError`).

Comment: try setting unicode in your program like `import sys`, `reload(sys)`,`sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')` add these lines to `doiterations.py` and try.

Comment: @shivsn Unfortunately, it did not work either both with cx_freeze and pyinstaller.

Answer (score 2):

At least in the case of cx_freeze an explanation can be found: https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issues/127/collectionssys-error

Unfortunately [Python Package Index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) does not provide a version of cx_freeze that includes the necessary changes. A new version of cx_Freeze can be installed after [Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266) has been installed. It is possible to install python packages from other locations than Python Package Index with *pip* command, in this case

```
pip install --upgrade https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/get/tip.zip
```

This needs to be done in *Anaconda prompt* that should be found from the *Start menu*. command prompt suffices if the PATH has been modified during the installation of Anaconda.

Comment: Again does not work. However, I might make mistakes. Please, check me.

1. During Step 6 I wrote `pip install --upgrade cx_freeze` as it did not allow me to write without `cx_freeze`. 
2. During Step 4 I started an usual Windows command prompt (cmd). Maybe I should have started another one?